# Проблема при использовании библиотеки auto-py-to-exe

Tags: компиляция, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Передо мне стояла задача из файла .py создать файл .exe, для последущего запуска на другом компьютере. Всё прошло успешно, auto-py-to-exe создал мне папку с большим количеством файлов и библиотек, и самое главное с моей экзешкой. На моём компьютере при запуске экзешке ,из папки куда он её скомпилировал, всё отлично запустилось. Я перекинул папку со всеми файлами на флешку и принёс её к другому компьютеру. Там возникла ошибка с отображением изображений(а именно, фон в программе и впринципе все картинки который там были). Как я понимаю это связано с путём к картинке когда создавалась экзэшка. Как можно это исправить, возможно ли как-нибудь собрать экзэшку чтобы все файлы в ней отображались на любом устройстве без сбоев. Спасибо!

Comment: Проблема может быть в вашем "компилируемом" коде, как в нём прописаны пути к ресурасм.

Comment: Это читали? https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/#the-one-file-resource-wrapper